# SQL Server 2005 Update query with Lookup Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables;

Technology Look Up table

```
OSID  OSValue  

1     UNIX             
2     ORACLE            
3     .NET 
4     SQL    
5     SAP  

------------------
```

Employee technology

```
empID   OSID

34      1
37      2
45      2
34      4
45      6
```

Employee ID NO 37 is no more using ORACLE . He shifted to SAP . That is OSID should b updated from 2 to 5 in the second table .

I have a temp table that has vales for technology and employee id

Please help me with 
- writing a query that joins both above tables
- Look up the ID of the SAP technology , and update the second table with that ID .

```
Update emp
Set emp.OSID = (Select OSID from technologylookup where OSValue = tmptbl.technologyname)
FROM employee_tech emp INNER JOIN #Temptbl tmptbl ON emp.emp_id = tmptbl.emp_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join your lookup table to the temp table, and then update the employee_tech table with the ID from that table

```
Update emp
   Set emp.OSID = tl.OSID
FROM employee_tech emp 
INNER JOIN #Temptbl tmptbl 
   ON emp.emp_id = tmptbl.emp_id
INNER JOIN technologylookup tl
   ON tl.OSValue COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = tmptbl.technologyname
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . Your answer seems right but I get the below error

Comment: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT after each table in the join

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head, untested:

```
update employee_tech
set osid = t.osid
from #Temptbl tmp
inner join employee_tech e on e.emp_id = tmp.emp_id
inner join technologylookup t on t.osvalue = tmp.technologyname
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'technology' in your temporary table is equal to the  ID, you can update like this.

```
UPDATE employee_tech
SET OSID = (SELECT technology FROM #Temptbl AS T INNER JOIN employee_tech AS E ON T.empID = E.empID)
```